# Sitecore SOLR Errors

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1

I am using SOLR with sitecore, on production environment, I am getting a lot of errors in SOLR log, but sites are working fine, I have **32 solr cores**, and I am using Solr version **4.10.3.0** with **Sitecore 8.1 update 2**, below is sample of these errors, any one can explain to me these errors :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most of the errors are self-descriptive, like this one:

```
undefined field: "Reckless"
```

tells that the field in question is not defined in the solr schema. Try to analyze the queries you system is accepting and the system sending these in.

The less obvious one:

```
Overlapping onDeckSearchers=2
```

is warning about warming searchers, in this case 2 of them concurrently. This means, that there were commits to the Solr index in a quick succession, each of which triggered a warming searcher. The reason it is wasteful is that even though the first searcher has warmed up and is ready to serve queries, it will be thrown away as the new searcher warms up and is ready to serve.